# Request body is empty in Express route

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am building an API with Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB. When I submit the form and use the `req` object in the route, the `req.body` object is empty.

`req.body` returns `{}` when I call the `get_user` function through the browser using postman at https://localhost:3000/users/0.

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo_server = require('./server')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var routes = require('./routes/users')
routes(app);

app.use(function(req, res) { 
    res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'});
});

app.listen(port);

mongo_server.mongo_connection

module.exports = app;
```

`userController.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    user = mongoose.model('users');

exports.get_user = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.id);
    user.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
        console.log(req.body);
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(user);
        });
    };
```

`userRoutes.js`:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../controllers/userController');
    app.route('/users/:userid')
       .get(users.get_user);
}
```

Comment: What are you sending to the server via postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing request parameters and request bodies. A request body is when you send information with the request like a payload, such as in a POST request when you send JSON to the server to, for example, create a new user:

```
{
  "username": "jd123",
  "email": "jd@example.com",
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

But in your case, you're looking for *parameters*, things passed through the URL like you've set up:

```
/users/:userid
```

That allows you to navigate to with a GET request:

```
/users/0
```

And then you can get the 0 as a string from **`req.params.userid`** not `req.body.id`. Request parameters and bodies are different. Parameters are for navigating to a varying route such as a user profile page, where the URL varies and reflects which route you want to go to by a user's ID.

Bodies are used for the payload of a request such as POSTing, PATCHing, and PUTing, giving information on what to update or create on the server.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I was confused about request parameters.